# Losing api response when delegate is changed

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am facing an issue using the Protocol in my app, I have created a control to manage api calls, and return the response to the delegate view controller. but my concern is for example:

I was at ViewController1 and requested an api to get admin profile for example, and assign api delegate to self meaning (`APIClient.delegate = self`) : ViewController1 will receive the response because it implemented the delegate of api client to have the response back

Now before the response comes back of get admin profile. i went to ViewController2 and assigned the `APIClient.delegate = self` and requested another api call here. Now the response of get admin profile came but it will be discard because the delegate is not equal to ViewController1 who did the request or not implementing the method to handle profile response!

Here is some of my code:

```
@objc protocol APIClientDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    @objc optional func getAdminProfileFinishedWithResponse(_ dictionary:NSMutableDictionary)
    @objc optional func getAdminProfileFailedWithError(_ error:NSError)
}



@objc class APIClient: APIClientDelegate {

   weak var delegate : APIClientDelegate?


  func getAdminProfile(_ postDictionary:NSMutableDictionary){


        self.get(getUserProfilePath, parameters: postDictionary, progress: nil, success: { (task, response) in

                if self.delegate != nil && self.delegate!.responds(to: #selector(APIClientDelegate.getAdminProfileFinishedWithResponse(_:))){
                    self.delegate!.getAdminProfileFinishedWithResponse!((response as! NSDictionary ).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary)
                }

        }) { (task, error) in

                if self.delegate != nil && self.delegate!.responds(to: #selector(APIClientDelegate.getAdminProfileFailedWithError(_:))){
                    self.delegate!.getAdminProfileFailedWithError!(error as NSError)
                }

        }
    }
}
```

If you get my point, if ViewController1 requested an api to be sure that the response doesn't get lost if the delegate is changed. Any idea of how to solve it dynamically, in background..etc?

Comment: Please add the whole block of code where `APIClient.delegate = self` line of is included.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Your solutions is kind of good, but this might make me loss the queue of requests. I'm just unsure ! what do you think ? @Mr.Bista

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you have create an object of object of `APIClient` each time you make an API call.

e.g.

```
let objClient = APIClient()
objClient.delegate = self
objClient.getAdminProfile(.....
```

by this way, the reference of each call will be contained and API calls won't overlap.

Comment: i have updated my code. I'm using singleton api client class, is it correct or should i don't used singleton ?

Comment: I don't think it is right to use singleton in this case.